# Merge Two Objects without Applying Subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

The UV mapping is trash when I apply the subdivision surface modifier.
So I want to export my model without having to apply it. Yet, when I try to merge two models into one I don't want the model without the subdivision surface modifier to be affected by the modifier.

Comment: That is not possible. In the first place, the subsurface modifier cannot export with the mesh unless you apply it.  Second, it is not possible to join the two meshes and have one part be effected by the modifier and the other not. You would need to apply it before joining.

Comment: this is strange. i have exported many models before. and they were not applyed to SDS even if they were affected by it . anyway it's sad to hear. but thanks anyway

Comment: I guessing it must automatically apply it when you export it.

Comment: the problem is that when it so manny faces. the uv mapping becomes trash. i want for exemple. make one part SDS. another non SDS. merge them togther and unwarp them. if i apply the sds the uv mapping will not be good. and it's need to be becuse i want to export and paint them in subsanse painter.